# Link redirect based on device

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a link in an email going to a video at url xxx.xxxxxxx.xx/zzz, where zzz is a unique id for that video. I need to redirect the user based on their device to the right location. If they are coming from an iPhone, it will direct them to a deep link. Otherwise, direct them to the original url.

I have the following which will be in a page linked to from the email, but its not quite right:

```
var host = document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname;

if(navigator.userAgent.match("iPhone") || navigator.userAgent.match("iPad")){
  deep link to redirect to here
}
else {
  window.location.replace(host);
}
```

as a diagram:

email link -> device redirect -> if iphone || ipad {go to deep link} else go to video link

Comment: I'm not sure the **string.match** function works like that, it expects a regex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Yep, definitely works.

Comment: yeah. it returns an array, it should be enough to pass the truthyness test. what's the behaviour you get? As it is now it looks like the else branch will reload the page causing the code to just execute again resulting in an endless loop. :D

Answer (score 1):

So figure out the answer:

Have the original link in this format:

```
<html>
<a href="newsletter-redirect.html?video=http://xxx.xxxxxx.xx/mXp">Video</a>
</html>
```

and the newsletter-redirect.html page will have the following javascript:

```
var video = document.location.search.split("?video=");

if(navigator.userAgent.match("iPhone") || navigator.userAgent.match("iPad")){
  window.location.replace("deep link code");
}
else {
  window.location.replace(video[1]);
}
```

This will redirect the user to the link http://xxx.xxxxx.xx/mXp if they are coming from a non-ios device.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. Dont forget that .match() uses a regular expression which requires escape characters. Then after you detect the iphone, ipod, ipad you just need to redirect using window.location property.

```js
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    window.location="DEEPLINKURL";
  }else{
     window.location="LINKURL";
    }
```